# transfer barcode characters to a Zebra printer using QB45

Tags: barcode

The following qb45 code partly operates my Zebra GC420D printer.

```
1 cls : locate 15, 30: input "type floppy code"; B$
3 cls : locate 12, 30: "Is Barcode ";B$
5 Locate 15, 30: "Confirm Y/N"; E$: IF E$ = "Y" OR E$ = "y" THEN 20 ELSE 1
20 LPRINT"^XA"
23 LPRINT"B3,N,175,Y"
25 LPRINT"N^FD, B$,  ^FS"
30 LPRINT "^PQ2"
35 LPRINT "^XZ"
40 LPRINT "end"
```

Two barcodes are produced which only code the string variable B$ not what B$ represents.  Do I need a text variable? How can I emulate a text variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable inside a quoted string.  Not sure what flavor of BASIC that is, but try:

```
LPRINT "^FD", B$, "^FS"
```

If that doesn't work, some BASICs use semicolon as the list separator to LPRINT:

```
LPRINT "^FD"; B$; "^FS"
```